# How can I edit the keyboard shortcuts in notes

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, notes.app

As the title says, how can I edit the shortcuts in the notes app?

Right now `Font Bigger` is obtained by pressing together **cmd** and **=** I would like to use **cmd** and **+** instead. Is there a way to change this setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to System Preferences → Keyboard → App Shortcuts.
2. Click the + to add a new shortcut.
3. Choose Notes.app, enter ‘Bigger’ as the Menu Title, then set the Keyboard Shortcut ‘⇧⌘=’.
4. Click Add. The new shortcut will be available for use and will show in the Notes menus as appropriate, under Format → Font → Bigger.